# Can a child process change a static variable shared by his parent?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, child-process

Can a child process change a static int shared by his parent process? Something similiar to this simple example:

```
static int changeMe = 1;
...
int main() {
   if (fork()=0){
      changeMe = 0;
   }
   wait(0);
   printf(1, "changeMe value is: %d., changeMe);
}
```

I know the child creates a clone of the parent memory. But i actually want that the child will change values at its parent - Is it possible?

Comment: [IPC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html), it's not so simple.

Comment: In a word, no.  If you want to do something like that, you could use shared memory.

Comment: the fork() starts a new process.  That process gets a copy of the parent data. so the child process does not have access to the parent data.

Comment: No. If you want to do this, you need to explicitly allocate shared memory *and* use synchronization primitives that ensure one process sees the changes the other makes.

Comment: regarding the presented code.   after the line: 'changeMe = 0; there needs to be an exit() statement.  otherwise the child process will continue executing the code (same code parent is executing) and the results could be confusing.  The child would have hung, forever, at the wait(0); statement.  And so would the parent, as the child would never exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not through fork, since you're creating a new process with a separate stack and address space. If you want to share variables, look at using threads.

Comment: Threads are not  the only solution, but yes they are a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to handle these sort of communication once you forked() is to use pipes, especially if you want "a private communication channel with the child".

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html
```